# If T is uniquely ergodic, must the infinite time average of a continuous function equal the function integrated against the ergodic measure?

Tags: ergodic-theory

Let $\mathbb{R}^n$ have the Borel sigma algebra given by the standard topology
Let $T:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^n$ be uniquely ergodic
where $\mu$ is the unique ergodic measure
Assume $\mu$ has bounded support and let $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function
Must the following hold for all $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$?

$\lim_{T\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{T}\sum_{k=0}^Tf(T^kx) = \int fd\mu$

Note that this is not a direct result [Birkhoffs Theorem](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/BirkhoffsErgodicTheorem.html) because I am interested in all $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: If I undestand the question correctly this is  an immediate application of the ergodic theorem. The limits exists a.e. by the theorem and the limit is the constant $\int f d\mu$ because $T$ is ergodic w.r.t. $\mu$.

Comment: this follows from basic properties of unique ergodicity (some make it a definition of uniquely ergodic).